# Implementing Payment Gateways in ASP.net Web Application

Tags: asp.net, paypal, payment-gateway, credit-card

I an developing a web application in ASP.Net using C#, under .Net Framework 4.0. Now its time to implement payment page in that application. I am asked to provide the facility of every payment mechanism (pay-pal, credit card, visa card, master card etc.)

Now to be honest i even don't know the difference among these card type :(. Please guide me how to achieve this and if possible also suggest the tentative time for implementing this.

Comment: @user492238 I gone through the paypal developer site and get some basic understanding of how to implement paypal. And planing to start coding from today. But i am confused, that do i need to create separate page for each payment method? I am not willing to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal can take just about all of these types - why not just have them process everything?
Its hard to give you an answer of implementation time as I have no idea what your application is like - but its fairly easy to setup.

Here is a paypal for dummies link:
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/adding-paypal-to-your-web-site.html